# Converting Second Order IVP to an Autonomous System With the Parameters Treated as Unknowns

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

> I am trying to convert the second order IVP $$\frac{d^2 y}{dt^2}-ty=\mu y^3 \ \ \text{with} \ \ y(2)=1, \ \ y'(2)=4$$ into an autonomous system of first order ODEs with the parameters treated as unknowns.

We let $x_1=y$, $x_2=y'$ and $x_3=t$. Hence, 
$$\vec{x'}=\begin{pmatrix}
x'_1 \\
x'_2 \\
x'_3 \\
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
x_2 \\
\mu x^3_1+x_3x_1 \\
1\\
\end{pmatrix}=f(\vec{x}),$$ with $$\vec{x(2)}=\begin{pmatrix}
x_1(2) \\
x_2(2) \\
x_3 (2)\\
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
4 \\
2\\
\end{pmatrix}.$$
What I have done here is convert the IVP into an autonomous system of first order ODEs. But how do I treat the parameters as unknowns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only parameter you have used is $\mu$ so I don't see any problem at all to define a 4th variable $x_4=\mu$ and let $x_4'=0$. I don't know why you want to treat it as a variable but by the way you can proceed exactly as for the t variable/parameter. So for instance you would get $x_2'=x_4x_1^3+x_3x_1$